# How to save pcap file to text file using tshark

Tags: text, pcap, tshark

I have a pcap file : a.pcap which contains udp packets.

I can save this a.pcap to text file (.txt) with wireshark GUI. (File -> Save as -> k12 text file).

How can I do the same thing with tshark from command line. I want **exactly the same output file** as (File -> Save as -> k12 text file).

I have tried commands like:

tshark -T pdml -r 1.pcap -T fields -e data > a.xml

This will result in writing udp payload to a.xml.Not the exact thing I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can save this a.pcap to text file (.txt) with wireshark GUI. (File -> Save as -> k12 text file).

"Text file" covers a number of text file formats, such as:

- a file showing the packet summaries as text (the topmost pane of Wireshark, by default);
- a file showing the packet details of each packet as text (showing, for each packet, the default middle pane of Wireshark);
- a file showing hex dumps of the packet data (showing, for each packet, the default bottommost pane of Wireshark);
- a combination of two of those, or of all three of those;
- a CSV file of columns from the packet summaries;
- a CSV file of particular fields from the packet;
- a PSML file showing, as XML, the components of the packet summaries;
- a PDML file showing, as XML, the components of the details of each packet;
- a JSON file showing the details of each packet;
- a C source file showing the raw hex data of the packets, with each packet being in a separate C array of byte values;
- a text packet capture format.

So there's no such thing as "the" text format to save a pcap file as; there are a bunch of choices.

"K12 text format" is a text packet capture format; it's what some Tektronix equipment can write out - in that sense, it's similar to writing out the raw hex data, plus some metadata.  However, from a user-interface sense, it's more like "Save As..." in Wireshark, because it's a capture file format.

The way you do that is with

```
tshark -F {output file format} -r {input file} -w {output file}
```

so, if you want to read the pcap file and write it out as a "K12 text format" file, you can do it with

```
tshark -F k12text -r a.pcap -w a.txt
```

You can also do this with editcap:

```
editcap -F k12text a.pcap a.txt
```

Comment: this gives me error `tshark: Live captures can only be saved in pcap or pcapng format.`

Comment: If you try to do a *live capture*, without `-r`, no, that won't work.  If you try to *read an existing capture file* by running `tshark` with the `-r` flag, that's *not* a live capture, so it will work.